link on click scroll into targeted div without whole body scrolling, javascript
when i click a particular section's link in link_div then i want to make scroll into the content_div's section.
i try with javascript, but i cannot properly handle this. this scroll with whole body element.
my page is like this
<body>
    <div>header/navbar</div>
    <div>hero section</div>
    <div class="container position-relative">
        <div class="row d-flex">
            <div class="col-3 link_div position-sticky">
                <ul>
                    <li><span onclick="showSection(section1)">Section 1</span></li>
                    <li><span onclick="showSection(section2)">Section 2</span></li>
                    <li><span onclick="showSection(section3)">Section 3</span></li>
                    <li><span onclick="showSection(section4)">Section 4</span></li>
                    <li><span onclick="showSection(section5)">Section 5</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9 content_div">
                <div id="section1" class="height-300"></div>
                <div id="section2" class="height-300"></div>
                <div id="section3" class="height-300"></div>
                <div id="section4" class="height-300"></div>
                <div id="section5" class="height-300"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

i use javascript's method like - scrollTo, scrollBy, scrollIntoView but anyone cannot work properly

function showSection(sectionId) {
    var targetSection = document.getElementById(sectionId);
    var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content_div');

    if (targetSection && contentDiv) {
        var contentDivRect = contentDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
        var sectionRect = targetSection.getBoundingClientRect();
        var scrollPosition = sectionRect.top - contentDivRect.top + contentDiv.scrollTop;
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);

    }
}

Here's the snippet:


function showSection(sectionId) {
  var targetSection = document.getElementById(sectionId);
  var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content_div');

  if (targetSection && contentDiv) {
    var contentDivRect = contentDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
    var sectionRect = targetSection.getBoundingClientRect();
    var scrollPosition = sectionRect.top - contentDivRect.top + contentDiv.scrollTop;
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);

  }
}
<body>
  <div>header/navbar</div>
  <div>hero section</div>
  <div class="container position-relative">
    <div class="row d-flex">
      <div class="col-3 link_div position-sticky">
        <ul>
          <li><span onclick="showSection(section1)">Section 1</span></li>
          <li><span onclick="showSection(section2)">Section 2</span></li>
          <li><span onclick="showSection(section3)">Section 3</span></li>
          <li><span onclick="showSection(section4)">Section 4</span></li>
          <li><span onclick="showSection(section5)">Section 5</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9 content_div">
        <div id="section1" class="height-300"></div>
        <div id="section2" class="height-300"></div>
        <div id="section3" class="height-300"></div>
        <div id="section4" class="height-300"></div>
        <div id="section5" class="height-300"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>



i also try this-
function showSection(sectionId) {
    var selectedSection = document.getElementById(sectionId);
    if (selectedSection) {
        const scrollOffset = targetElement.offsetTop - scrollableDiv.offsetTop; 
        scrollableDiv.scrollTop = scrollOffset; 
        selectedSection.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
}


Please go read up on the basics of how to add an event handler to an HTML element. <span showSection(section1)> is not doing that.

maybe you should read up on <a>nchors that can reference an element with an id. No need for JS.

@CBroe it's not problem. i use any html element it should be work

@tacoshy if its work only with  then i would not made question here

Your code was very close to the solution. You did not wrap quotes around the section id, you searched for a class as if it was an id and did not do the scroll and you overcomplicated incorrectly the scroll computation. Fixing these issues also fixed your code, here's the snippet:


function showSection(sectionId) {
    var targetSection = document.getElementById(sectionId);
    var contentDiv = document.querySelector('.content_div');

    if (targetSection && contentDiv) {
        var contentDivRect = contentDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
        var sectionRect = targetSection.getBoundingClientRect();
        var scrollPosition = sectionRect.top - contentDivRect.top + contentDiv.scrollTop;
        contentDiv.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);

    }
}
div.height-300 {
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div.content_div {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 300px;
}
<body>
    <div>header/navbar</div>
    <div>hero section</div>
    <div class="container position-relative">
        <div class="row d-flex">
            <div class="col-3 link_div position-sticky">
                <ul>
                    <li><span onclick="showSection('section1')">Section 1</span></li>
                    <li><span onclick="showSection('section2')">Section 2</span></li>
                    <li><span onclick="showSection('section3')">Section 3</span></li>
                    <li><span onclick="showSection('section4')">Section 4</span></li>
                    <li><span onclick="showSection('section5')">Section 5</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9 content_div">
                <div id="section1" class="height-300">1</div>
                <div id="section2" class="height-300">2</div>
                <div id="section3" class="height-300">3</div>
                <div id="section4" class="height-300">4</div>
                <div id="section5" class="height-300">5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>




hi, i already try it. but i cannot get desired output, if i have few section/div before my  testing(here- container) div then scroll to top whole body with my testing div

@MDMeadulIslam I'm sorry, but I don't understand what scenario is failing.

i want to scroll into the container div only, not whole body

@MDMeadulIslam thanks for pointing that out, I have edited my answer accordingly. Please test the Fiddle again.

There is no need to use JS for this. HTML has a default  "jump to element" tool. You simply just need to use an <a>nchor where you use a hash (#) to reference an ID. This either works within the same page or even on external pages.


html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/* for demonstration porpuse only */
.content_div > div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  min-height: 60vh;
}
  
<div class="row d-flex">
  <div class="col-3 link_div position-sticky">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section4">Section 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section5">Section 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9 content_div">
    <div id="section1" class="height-300">div 1</div>
    <div id="section2" class="height-300">div 2</div>
    <div id="section3" class="height-300">div 3</div>
    <div id="section4" class="height-300">div 4</div>
    <div id="section5" class="height-300">div 5</div>
  </div>
</div>




its not my question's answer

It is. You have a XY issue. You so focused on fixing Y that you miss that if you would do X right you would not even have Y.
